# How to convert 3D histogram to heatmap

Tags: matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

I am wondering if there is a way to map a 3D histogram from matplotlib to a color heatmap?
For example I have a [3D histogram](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/mplot3d/hist3d.html) as [image]

How can I convert it to a heatmap where the height is shown as color of the heatmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Matplotlib there is also [`Axes.hist2d`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.hist2d.html) or [`pyplot.hist2d`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d.html).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng

rng = default_rng(0)

x, y = rng.uniform(0, 4, size=(2, 100))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist2d(x, y, bins=4, range=[[0, 4], [0, 4]], cmap='Blues')
ax.set_aspect('equal')

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

To add a colorbar to estimate the counts in each bin you can use the following code. I've also demonstrated how to obtain the resultant hist matrix that matplotlib generates.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng

rng = default_rng(0)

x, y = rng.uniform(0, 4, size=(2, 100))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
hist, xedges, yedges, im = ax.hist2d(
    x, y, bins=4, range=[[0, 4], [0, 4]], cmap='Blues'
)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax, label='count')

print(hist)
# [[ 5.  7.  6.  4.]
#  [ 5.  6.  4.  7.]
#  [ 5.  8.  6.  6.]
#  [ 7.  1.  9. 14.]]

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution works via seaborn (an extension of  matplotlib specialized in statistical visualization):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

x, y = np.random.rand(2, 100) * 4
sns.histplot(x=x, y=y, bins=4, binrange=[[0, 4], [0, 4]])
```

[image: seaborn 2D histplot]

With pure matplotlib, a possibility with `plt.imshow()`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

x, y = np.random.rand(2, 100) * 4
hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=4, range=[[0, 4], [0, 4]])

plt.imshow(hist.T, origin='lower', extent=[xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]], cmap='Blues')
plt.xticks(xedges)
plt.yticks(yedges)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image: mimicking hist2d with imshow]

Seaborn doesn't return calculated values. You could use numpy for the calculations, and `sns.heatmap()` to display the histogram including annotations. As `sns.heatmap()` uses "categorical" x and y axes, the edge labels need to be assigned in a special way.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

x, y = np.random.rand(2, 100) * 4
hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=4, range=[[0, 4], [0, 4]])

ax = sns.heatmap(hist.T, annot=True)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(xedges)), xedges)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(yedges)), yedges, rotation=0)
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.heatmap of 2d histogram, with annotations]

Comment: Thanks, when using seaborn is there a way to show the height of each box (i.e.number of elements that are in that bin) on the fig so I know their values ?