# How to increase the resolution of axis when plotting via hist2d

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using the following code I create a 2d histogram.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

x, y = np.random.rand(2, 1000) * 10
hist, xedges, yedges, im = plt.hist2d(x, y, bins=10, range=[[0, 10], [0, 10]])

for i in range(len(hist)):
    for j in range(len(hist[i])):
        plt.text(xedges[i] + (xedges[i + 1] - xedges[i]) / 2,
                 yedges[j] + (yedges[j + 1] - yedges[j]) / 2,
                 hist[i][j], ha="center", va="center", color="w")
plt.show()
```

It looks like the following

[image]

I am wondering if there is a way to increase the axis details such that the x and y axis are like `[0, 1, 2, ..., 8, 9, 10]`. Basically, instead of jumping in steps of 2, I want to see all the integers in the range.

Comment: Also, why not use [`seaborn.heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) for this? Just be aware that one of the versions has a bug where it only shows the first row of annotations.

Comment: @jared yes that was answering my question, thanks! to your second question: I dont know how to use heatmap for that purpose.

Comment: Remove the double `for` loop and replace it with `seaborn.heatmap(hist, annot=True)`.

Comment: See also the last part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77790287/12046409) to your earlier question.